# Why is my sprite quality in the game window so much worse than my sprite quality in the editor and in the png file?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, import, image-quality

When I look open the image directly from the file or in the unity editor, it looks fine.

[Sprites in editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47vVT.png)

However, when I press the 'play' button and go into the game view, the quality gets a lot worse.

[Sprites in Game Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVfaL.png)

I don't think the problem is my scale, because the quality is bad regardless of my scale. Here are the [import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H6yj.png) that I'm using. How can I make the quality better in the actual game?

EDIT: Still haven't found or gotten any answers to this.

Comment: its your pixels per unit usually..

Comment: my pixels per unit is 100, how is that related?

Comment: pixels per unity determines the resolution of the sprite, and if you get it wrong it looks horrid.. so if your normal pixels would be say 32 per unit and youve said 100, its going to be scaling it down with hell of a loss.. similarly if your pixels per unit were supposed to be 128 and you picked 16.. it would look hella chunky check what your other sprites are set to, its probably not 100

Comment: all of my sprites are set to 100 pixels per unit...

Comment: well when you click on the sprites in your asset list to show the import settings theres a picture at the bottom, and it will have some words and numbers at the front theres usually something like 128x128..... that is the number to match

Comment: I drew all of my sprites with 100x100 intentionally, so that is what is says for all of them.